How to realize CVRPTW in IBM ILOG CPLEX with various data and size
Can't realize CVRPTW (Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows) in IBM ILOG CPLEX with adequate solution.
My .mod code:
int n = ...; // Set of vertices.
int nVehicles = ...; // Number of vehicles.
range N = 0..n-1; // Range of all points (including depot).
range C = 1..n-1; // Range of all clients (excluding depot).
range V = 0..nVehicles-1; // Range of all vehicles.

int c[N][N] = ...;    // Transportation cost.
dvar boolean x[N][N][V]; // 1 if the k-th vehicle goes from i to j, otherwise 0.
dvar int+ Z[V];
int Q = ...; // Vehicle capacity.
int d[C] = ...; // Client demand.
dvar int+ s[N][V]; // Arrival time.
int t[N][N] = ...;    // Transportation time.
int a[N] = ...;       // Start of time windows.
int b[N] = ...;       // End of time windows.

// 1. Objective function: minimize total transportation cost.
minimize sum(k in V) Z[k];

subject to {
    // All vehicles depart from the depot at time 0.
    //forall(k in V)
        //s[0][k] == 0; 
        
    // 2. Each client is visited exactly once.
    forall(i in C)
        sum(k in V, j in N) x[i][j][k] == 1;

    // 3. Capacity constraint.
    forall(k in V)
        sum(i in C, j in N) (d[i] * x[i][j][k]) <= Q;
        
    // 4. Each vehicle starts its route from the depot.
    forall(k in V)
        sum(j in N) x[0][j][k] == 1;
        
    // 5. Movement between clients.
    forall(k in V, h in C)
        sum(i in N) x[i][h][k] == sum(j in N) x[h][j][k];
        
    // 6. Each vehicle returns to the depot.
    forall(k in V)
        sum(i in N) x[i][0][k] == 1; // Possibly 0 instead of n-1.
        
    // 7. Departure time from one point and arrival time at another point.
    forall(i in N, j in N, k in V)
        s[i][k] + t[i][j] <= s[j][k] + (1 - x[i][j][k]) * 10000; // Large number to disable constraint when x[i][j][k] = 0.
        
    // 8. Time window constraints.
    forall(i in N, k in V)
        a[i] <= s[i][k] <= b[i];
    
    // 10. Constraint on using a specified number of vehicles.
    sum(k in V, j in N) x[0][j][k] <= nVehicles;
    
    // Constraint linking variable Z[k] with total transportation cost
    forall(k in V)
        Z[k] == sum(i in N, j in N) (c[i][j] * x[i][j][k]);
}

.dat code:
n = 6; // Set of vertices.
nVehicles = 4; // Number of vehicles.

// Transportation cost.
c = [
    [0, 10, 15, 20, 30, 25],
    [10, 0, 9, 14, 23, 18],
    [15, 9, 0, 10, 12, 25],
    [20, 14, 10, 0, 11, 15],
    [30, 23, 12, 11, 0, 12],
    [25, 18, 25, 15, 12, 0]
];

// Transportation time.
t = [
    [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7],
    [3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6],
    [4, 3, 2, 0, 3, 5],
    [5, 5, 4, 3, 0, 2],
    [6, 7, 6, 5, 2, 0]
];

Q = 100; // Vehicle capacity.
d = [2, 3, 4, 2, 1]; // Demand.

// Time windows
a = [0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12];
b = [100, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18];

In solution I get zeros in Z. When I change the c matrix diagonally on big numbers (e. g. 100000), I get 600000 100000 100000 100000.
The results I would like to get should look like this:
Sample Output
Suppose we have 4 vehicles and 5 clients. The results might look like this:

Route for Vehicle 1: Depot → Client 3 → Client 1 → Depot

Route for Vehicle 2: Depot → Client 2 → Client 4 → Client 5 → Depot

Route for Vehicle 3: Depot (unused)

Route for Vehicle 4: Depot (unused)

Total cost: 150 (e.g., total distance or route time)

Arrival times:

Vehicle 1: Client 3 — 5, Client 1 — 9

Vehicle 2: Client 2 — 4, Client 4 — 8, Client 5 — 12





Could https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/vrptwcpo.mod be a good starting point ?

Yes, it could. Thank you! I'll try to figure out how to add capacity, but this solution also fine for me!

capacity constraint is taken care of by  dexpr int load[veh in vehicles] = sum(v in clientVisits) presenceOf(tvisitInterval[v][veh])*v.quantity;

starting point
.mod
using CP;

tuple Node {
    key string nodeID;
    int x;
    int y;
}
{Node} nodes = ...; 

tuple Visit { 
            key int visitID;
            string nodeID; 
            int quantity; 
            int minTime; 
            int maxTime; 
            int dropTime; 
              };
{Visit} clientVisits = ...;   

tuple Vehicle {
                key string vehicleID;   
                string firstVisitID;
                string lastVisitID;
                int capacity;
                int start;
                int end;
            }   
{Vehicle} vehicles = ...;                               

int firstDepotVisitID = min(v in clientVisits) v.visitID - 1;
int lastDepotVisitID = max(v in clientVisits) v.visitID + 1;
Visit firstDepotVisit = <firstDepotVisitID,"depot",0,0,230,0>;
Visit lastDepotVisit = <lastDepotVisitID,"depot",0,0,230,0>;
{Visit} allVisits = clientVisits union
            // Needs to be generalized for multiple depots
            {firstDepotVisit, lastDepotVisit };
            
int xPerVisit[i in allVisits]=item(nodes,<i.nodeID>).x; 
int yPerVisit[i in allVisits]=item(nodes,<i.nodeID>).y; 

int horizon = max (v in allVisits) v.maxTime;

// Create transition distance
tuple triplet { int c1; int c2; int d; };
{triplet} Dist = { 
    
        <ord(allVisits,v1), ord(allVisits,v2), 
        ftoi(round(sqrt(pow(n2.x-n1.x,2)+pow(n2.y-n1.y,2))))> 
           | v1,v2 in allVisits, n1, n2 in nodes : v1.nodeID == n1.nodeID && v2.nodeID == n2.nodeID }; 
  
dvar interval visitInterval[v in clientVisits] in v.minTime..(v.maxTime+v.dropTime) size v.dropTime;
dvar interval wtvisitInterval [v in clientVisits] size v.dropTime..horizon;
dvar interval tvisitInterval  [v in allVisits][veh in vehicles] 
                  optional(v.visitID!=firstDepotVisitID && v.visitID!=lastDepotVisitID);
dvar sequence route[veh in vehicles] in all(v in allVisits) tvisitInterval[v][veh] 
                                  types all(v in allVisits) ord(allVisits,v); 
dvar interval truck [veh in vehicles] optional;


 
execute {
  cp.param.TimeLimit               = 10
}

dexpr int nonTravelTime = sum(v in clientVisits) sizeOf(wtvisitInterval[v]);
dexpr float travelTime = sum(veh in vehicles) endOf(tvisitInterval[lastDepotVisit][veh]) - nonTravelTime;
dexpr int nbUsed = sum(veh in vehicles) presenceOf(truck[veh]);
dexpr int load[veh in vehicles] = sum(v in clientVisits) presenceOf(tvisitInterval[v][veh])*v.quantity;

minimize staticLex(nbUsed,travelTime); 
subject to  {

  forall(v in clientVisits ) {
    endAtEnd(wtvisitInterval[v], visitInterval[v]);
    startBeforeStart(wtvisitInterval[v], visitInterval[v]);
  }
  forall(veh in vehicles) {
    span (truck[veh], all(v in clientVisits) tvisitInterval[v][veh]);
    noOverlap(route[veh], Dist);          // Travel time
    startOf(tvisitInterval[firstDepotVisit][veh])==0;     // Truck t starts at time 0 from depot
    last (route[veh],tvisitInterval[lastDepotVisit] [veh]); // Truck t returns at depot
    load[veh] <= veh.capacity;                       // Truck capacity
  }
  forall(v in clientVisits)
    alternative(wtvisitInterval[v], all(t in vehicles) tvisitInterval[v][t]); // Truck selection


}
 
execute {
  writeln(nbUsed + " vehicles are used");
  writeln("Total travelled distance is " + travelTime); 
}

.dat
nodes = {<"depot" 35 35> <"node1" 41 49> <"node2" 35 17>
         <"node3" 55 45> <"node4" 55 20> <"node5" 15 30>
         <"node6" 25 39> <"node7" 20 50> <"node8" 10 43>
         <"node9" 55 60> <"node10" 30 60> <"node11" 20 65>
         <"node12" 50 35> <"node13" 30 25> <"node14" 15 10>
         <"node15" 30 5> <"node16" 10 20> <"node17" 5 30>
         <"node18" 20 40> <"node19" 15 60> <"node20" 45 65>};
clientVisits = {<1 "node1" 10 0 204 10>
         <2 "node2" 7 0 202 10>
         <3 "node3" 13 0 197 10>
         <4 "node4" 19 149 159 10>
         <5 "node5" 26 0 199 10>
         <6 "node6" 3 0 208 10>
         <7 "node7" 5 0 198 10>
         <8 "node8" 9 95 105 10>
         <9 "node9" 16 97 107 10>
         <10 "node10" 16 0 194 10>
         <11 "node11" 12 67 77 10>
         <12 "node12" 19 0 205 10>
         <13 "node13" 23 159 169 10>
         <14 "node14" 20 0 187 10>
         <15 "node15" 8 61 71 10>
         <16 "node16" 19 0 190 10>
         <17 "node17" 2 0 189 10>
         <18 "node18" 12 0 204 10>
         <19 "node19" 17 0 187 10>
         <20 "node20" 9 0 188 10>};
vehicles = {<"vehicle1" "depot" "depot" 200 0 230>
         <"vehicle2" "depot" "depot" 200 0 230>
         <"vehicle3" "depot" "depot" 200 0 230>
         <"vehicle4" "depot" "depot" 200 0 230>
         <"vehicle5" "depot" "depot" 200 0 230>};

